# PHP: limitation of variable variables

Tags: php, indirection

In php I can do this:

```
$class = 'Notes';
echo $class::message();
```

but it seems that from within a method, I can't do this:

```
echo ($this->myClass)::message();
```

and also cannot do this:

```
echo someFunctionThatReturnsClassName()::message();
```

Can anybody explain why? And give some rules about when and how this indirection mechanism works?

Thank you 
Gidi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with variable variables, it is an issue with PHP not allowing this syntax. There is a proposal for fixing this in the core, however this one has not been accepted yet: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall (and also http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing)

Comment: Thank you, this answers very well my second example, bu not my first

Comment: Well yes, as your first one in theory is the same: by adding brackets (), you tell the PHP interpreter to execute that part of code and then call a static method on that one. Which will fails. If you do $temp = ($this->myClass); $temp::message(), it will work like a charm.

Comment: Not sure about your point with adding brackets. $this->myClass::message() will not work as well. I know that using a $temp will do the job, my question is why, how $this->var is different from simpy $var.

Comment: Without the brackets, you have a special situation. PHP treats $this->var as getting a string value. If you say $this->var::foo(), you are calling foo() on a string and not on a "variable variable".

Comment: interesting, so will this: $class='Notes'; ($class)::message(); fail as well? What about this: ('Notes')::message(); and this: (Notes)::message()?

Comment: ($class)::message(); may work, as I *think* PHP optimizes it to the version without brackets. The 2nd one will probably not work as well as the third one. It's been a while since my PHP certification exam :-)